# iOS tab bar in the middle of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I was looking around but cannot find any info how to create a tab bar that will contain 2 controllers in the middle of the screen.

I write UI for my apps programatically BTW, i don't use storyboards.

Here is a sample from Vimeo, I want to do something similar.

[Vimeo sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3eWB.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean as a Tab Bar  on provided screen?

Answer (score 0):

As I see on sample - this tab bar is **UISegmentedControl** element (and it is not UITabBar what can be messing up with the terms). It has delegates methods what allow you to respond to its selection and on these events you can change or show-hide views or controllers included in your ui.